# Update all entries with old date SQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I am writing a PHP script to remove all entires in a sql table where the date (stored in the ENDDATE column). I Currently have

```
    if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 

$sql = "UPDATE sm_admins SET flags='' WHERE ENDDATE > CURRENT_DATE() ";


if ($conn->query($sql) === TRUE) {
    echo "Record deleted successfully";
} else {
    echo "Error deleting record: " . $conn->error;
}
$conn->close();
```

However this does not work, any thoughts?

Comment: please define old date in this context.

Comment: to remove/delete it's DELETE not UPDATE

Comment: Do you want to delete record from the DB (remove rows) or just want to make end-date blank??? Because you are not deleting the record, you are just updating the record. (please see delete statement in MySQL and also end date should be less than the current date not greater than

Comment: Then ENDDATE should be less than CURRENT_DATE() Yesterday can never be greater than today.

Comment: and older `WHERE ENDDATE > CURRENT_DATE()` this is "more than", you want `<` - Edit: I didn't see yours @JayBlanchard GMTA ;-)

Comment: you changed your title, but the body of the question still contains *"I am writing a PHP script to **remove** all entires"*

Comment: so again `WHERE ENDDATE < CURRENT_DATE()` - "less than `<`", not "greater than `>`"

Answer (score -1):

Then ENDDATE should be less than CURRENT_DATE() Yesterday can never be greater than today

Comment: *lol* - yeah, 3 people said that before this but you didn't ask anyone to post an answer, you just made it your own.

Comment: @ShaileshSingh To be perfectly honest, I didn't see your comment and Jay's when I wrote mine and the credit really goes out to you because yours was first. If you look at the timestamps, you'll see just how close they are *lol*

Comment: Wow, a straight up copy and paste! LOL!